# Micronaut ApplicationContext creation for package

Tags: java, package, micronaut, applicationcontext

In Spring, it is easy to create ApplicationContext that uses only classes defined in a given package. How to achieve that in Micronaut?

I write:

```
ApplicationContext context =
    ApplicationContext.builder()
        .args(args)
        .packages("org.kalamity.server")
        .start();

context.getBean(MessageEventListener.class);
```

But beans from foreign packages are created and injected. I know, that Micronaut works on compile time, so it might be completely impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When looking into `io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContextBuilder#build`, we'll find this:

```
if (!packages.isEmpty()) {
    for (String aPackage : packages) {
        environment.addPackage(aPackage);
    }
}
```

Doc for Environment#addPackage says:

> Add an application package. Application packages are candidates for
> scanning for tools that need it (such as JPA or GORM). Params: pkg –
> The package to add Returns: This environment

Hence, I believe it's not possible to limit context using a list of packages like in the question with Micronaut out-of-the-box.

However, you may use *@Requires* annotation to load parts of the context.
https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/#conditionalBeans

Source code from Micronaut 3.2.1

Comment: You are correct, environments solve my problem. I've created a ```package-info.java``` with  ```@Configuration
@Requires(env = "server")``` annotations and it worked as intended!